# Issue With Jackson and rest easy

Tags: java, json, rest

I have a Jackson provider like below.

```
public class JacksonConfig  extends JacksonJsonProvider {

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Object value, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String,Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        System.out.println("Test Success");
    }
}
```

also in my web.xml I have the below

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>
            com.alcatel.axs.webapps.providers.JacksonConfig
        </param-value>
  </context-param>
```

But my provider is not getting called when a rest service is called. Please let me know whats the issue.

Comment: Have you tried annotate JacksonConfig with @Provider?

Comment: yeap, but same result

Comment: Have you tried @Produces("application/json")?

Comment: Yeap, but that doesn't make an sense here

Comment: As per [jaxrs spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/index.html), section 3.6, inheritance of
class annotations is not supported. So it makes sense to put JacksonJsonProvider's produces (`@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "text/json"})` here. I asked because you probably have other provider used, some with better MediaType or better java type than JacksonJsonProvider's Object. So which provider is it?